# error in gitlab when building a project with grpc

Tags: c++, cmake, protocol-buffers, grpc

Locally it builds the project with grpc. but on gitlab it gives an error. Does anyone have any ideas? Locally, everything builds and works well. I get the problem when I use CI on gitlab. What could this error mean? I don't understand what exactly is required? I've also tried running with different compilers - the error persists.

```
$ cmake --build .
[  4%] Running C++ gRPC compiler on include/protocol/proto/service.proto
[  8%] Running cpp protocol buffer compiler on /builds/k-morozov/appchat/build/src/protocol
Could not map to virtual file: /builds/k-morozov/appchat/build/src/protocol: Input file is a directory.
make[2]: *** [src/protocol/CMakeFiles/protocol_lib.dir/build.make:63: src/protocol/protocol.pb.h] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:93: src/protocol/CMakeFiles/protocol_lib.dir/all] Error 2
```

cmake:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
set(PROTOBUF_FILES
  "include/protocol/proto/messages.proto"
)
set(PROTOS_FILES
  ${PROTOBUF_FILES}
  "include/protocol/proto/service.proto"
)

list(APPEND CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_CURRENT_LIST_DIR}/cmake")
find_package(Protobuf REQUIRED)
find_package(GRPC REQUIRED)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)

set(PROTO_SRC_DIR ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR})
file(MAKE_DIRECTORY ${PROTO_SRC_DIR})
include_directories(${PROTO_SRC_DIR})

protobuf_generate_cpp(PROTO_SRCS PROTO_HDRS ${PROTO_SRC_DIR} ${PROTOS_FILES})
grpc_generate_cpp(GRPC_SRCS GRPC_HDRS ${PROTO_SRC_DIR} ${PROTOS_FILES})

set(PROTOCOL_LIB_NAME protocol_lib)
add_library(${PROTOCOL_LIB_NAME} STATIC)

target_sources(${PROTOCOL_LIB_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/include/protocol/protocol.h
    PRIVATE
        ${PROTO_HDRS}
        ${PROTO_SRCS}
        ${GRPC_SRCS}
        "include/protocol/command_table.h"
)

set_target_properties(${PROTOCOL_LIB_NAME} PROPERTIES
        CXX_STANDARD 17
        CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON
)

target_compile_options(${PROTOCOL_LIB_NAME} PRIVATE "-fPIC")
target_link_libraries(${PROTOCOL_LIB_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        gpr
        gRPC::grpc++
        protobuf::libprotobuf
        gRPC::grpc++_reflection
    PRIVATE
        pthread
        project_sanitizers
)

include_directories(${Protobuf_INCLUDE_DIRS})

target_include_directories(${PROTOCOL_LIB_NAME}
    PUBLIC
        "./include"
        ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/src/protocol/
    PRIVATE
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}
        ${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}
)
```

Comment: It writes that compiler is run for the file `/builds/k-morozov/appchat/build/src/protocol`. Do you have this file? Is it a file or a directory?

Comment: it is the directory where the *.pb.h files are store

Comment: Actually, the line `Running cpp protocol buffer compiler ...` is from [Protobuf module](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.5/module/FindProtobuf.html), not from grpc one. You use `protobuf_generate_cpp` function, which signature is `protobuf_generate_cpp (<SRCS> <HDRS> [<ARGN>...])`. That is, every parameter after the second one is treated as proto file. And among those parameters you pass `${PROTO_SRC_DIR}`, which is **directory**, not a **file**. It seems that the error message is exactly about that parameter.